# "Piece of cake" vs "a piece of cake"

Tags: articles

What's the difference between phrases "piece of cake" and "a piece of cake"?

This question comes from reading [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/105646/35336) to a question on puzzling.stackexchange.com and its first comment (which says that *The first line doesn't say "I'm a piece of cake", it says "I'm piece of cake"*).

Comment: I don't see a comment - maybe it has been deleted. The title says "I'm piece of cake", but that may just be carelessness since the question itself begins "I'm **a** piece of cake". There is no special meaning to the version without an article.

Comment: It appears that the typo you're referring to has been corrected.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "a piece of cake" means just what you'd expect. A piece of a cake.  For example:

> "Mary, would you like a piece of cake?"

The phrase "piece of cake" is an idiom that is often used to express that a job or task is easy or even trivial in the speaker's estimation.  For example:

> "Bob, my roof is leaking and I'm not sure what to do."

> "I'll fix it for you, piece of cake."

Comment: "That will be *a piece of cake*" also invokes the idiom, so I'm not sure it's all that clear. I think the meaning is only distinguishable in context.